# AngularJS Multiple GET requests, only first returning correctly

Tags: angularjs, promise, ionic-framework, angular-promise

I have the following in my controller:

```
ApiRequest.get('locations').then(function(locations) {
    $scope.locations = locations.locations;
});

ApiRequest.get('sublocations').then(function(sublocations) {
    $scope.sublocations = sublocations.sublocations;
});

ApiRequest.get('varieties').then(function (varieties) {
    $scope.varieties = varieties.varieties;
});

ApiRequest.get('tasks').then(function(tasks) {
    $scope.tasks = tasks.tasks;
});

ApiRequest.get('customers').then(function(customers) {
    $scope.customers = customers.customers;
});

ApiRequest.get('batches').then(function(batches) {
    $scope.batches = batches.batches;
    $ionicLoading.hide();
});
```

The data from each of these requests goes on to poplate select boxes in a form.

Here is my APIRequest service:

```
return {

        get: function(entity) {
            if($rootScope.online == false) {
                var data = {};
                data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data-' + entity));
                console.log(data);
                deferred.resolve(data);
            } else {
                $http.get($rootScope.baseUrl + entity).success(function(data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                })
            }

            return deferred.promise;

        },
}
```

It would appear that for some reason the results aren't getting back from the service on time to display them in the view.

Is this something to do with the way I am handling the promise?

Comment: What are returned in anothers? And which code is executed, "online: false or true"? Could you add all code of APIRequest please.

Comment: The only one actually returning correct is $scope.locations. the rest show undefined on load

Well online is if the device is online or not, either one it still behaves the same, $scope.locations is populated on view load but the rest are undefined until seemingly a touch later when its too late.

Comment: Well I can't see code to save values loaded from internet into LocalStorage, so I asked which one is executed online or offline. APIRequest is a "factory" or "service", because this behavior could happen due to different initializations of them.

Comment: ApiRequest is a factory. 

The data is definitely there and being loaded in the factory that  console.log(data); in the factory is showing correct.

Comment: in fact in my controller, if I console.log(sublocations); in the sublocations part it actually returns me the locations var, however the service is showing that data is in fact data.sublocations not data.locations like the scope is thinking it is?

Does any of that make sense lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first look, you declared the promise with $q outside your function as global (because I don't see inside). Try this one:

```
get: function(entity) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if($rootScope.online == false) {
            var data = {};
            data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data-' + entity));
            console.log(data);
            deferred.resolve(data);
        } else {
            $http.get($rootScope.baseUrl + entity).success(function(data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            })
        }

        return deferred.promise;

    },
```

Comment: Seems correct because you could resolve or reject only once.

Comment: thats funny, I actually noticed that and half way through rewriting I saw your response. Thats solved it! And it actually solves another issue I was having with push requests so thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 1):

your current implementation has little to no error handling and is executing multiple API requests in parallel; I would recommend chaining the promises.

```
ApiRequest.get('locations').then(function(locations) {
    $scope.locations = locations.locations;

    return ApiRequest.get('sublocations');
}).then(function(sublocations) {
    $scope.sublocations = sublocations.sublocations;

    return ApiRequest.get('varieties')
}).then(function (varieties) {
    $scope.varieties = varieties.varieties;

    return ApiRequest.get('tasks')
}).then(function(tasks) {
    $scope.tasks = tasks.tasks;

    return ApiRequest.get('customers')
}).then(function(customers) {
    $scope.customers = customers.customers;

    return ApiRequest.get('batches')
}).then(function(batches) {
    $scope.batches = batches.batches;

    $ionicLoading.hide();
}, function(_error) {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    console.log(_error);
});
```

and then your service can be simplified; the `$http` client returns a promise and using `$q.when` can return a promise also

```
    get: function(entity) {
        if($rootScope.online == false) {
            var data = {};
            data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data-' + entity));
            console.log(data);
            $q.when(data);
        } else {
            return $http.get($rootScope.baseUrl + entity)
        }
    },
```